# eval-last-sexp produces unnecessary void-variable error when using a macro containing eval

Tags: interactive, defun

Suppose I have defined the following macro:

```
(defmacro mymacro (a) "" (eval a))
```

If I then use `eval-last-sexp` (i.e. `C-x C-e`) to evaluate the following,

```
(defun somefcn (b) "" (mymacro b))
```

I get the error `(void-variable b)`. However, if I evaluate the definition another way (e.g. using `eval-expression`), it evaluates fine and works fine.

Note that the following expression evaluates without a problem

```
(defun somefcn (a) "" (mymacro a))
```

What is going on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After looking through the [GNU Emacs Lisp Reference Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/elisp.html), I realized that there is a subsection of "Common Problems Using Macros" called "Evaluating Macro Arguments in Expansion" which explains this issue.

The basic problem is that, when a macro is compiled as opposed to interpreted, the first evaluation of the macro is inserted into function definitions in place of the macro. Thus, my macro is actually calling `eval` on the not-defined variable `b`, hence returning an error. Basically, one should avoid using `eval` in the initial part of macro evaluations.